# Web scraping from wikipedia tables in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some data from the following wikipedia table:
[image]

Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aire-la-Ville

I am using this code to scrape Area, Elevation, and density using css selectors. I am storing the data in canton_table but only getting the elevation data and not for the other variables.

My code:

```
# Get labels and data
  labels <- current_html %>% html_elements(css = ".infobox-label") %>% html_text()
  data <- current_html %>% html_elements(css = ".infobox-data") %>% html_text()
```

Output for labels and data variables:

```
> labels
 [1] "Country"         "Canton"          "District"       
 [4] " • Mayor"        " • Total"        "Elevation"      
 [7] " • Total"        " • Density"      "Time zone"      
[10] " • Summer (DST)" "Postal code(s)"  "SFOS number"    
[13] "Surrounded by"   "Website"     

>data
[1] "Switzerland"                                                                                                                       
 [2] "Geneva"                                                                                                                            
 [3] "n.a."                                                                                                                              
 [4] "MaireRaymond Gavillet"                                                                                                             
 [5] "6.50 km2 (2.51 sq mi)"                                                                                                             
 [6] "428 m (1,404 ft)"                                                                                                                  
 [7] "11,609"                                                                                                                            
 [8] "1,800/km2 (4,600/sq mi)"                                                                                                           
 [9] "UTC+01:00 (Central European Time)"                                                                                                 
[10] "UTC+02:00 (Central European Summer Time)"                                                                                          
[11] "1234,1255"                                                                                                                         
[12] "6645"                                                                                                                              
[13] "Bossey (FR-74), Carouge, Chêne-Bougeries, Étrembières (FR-74), Gaillard (FR-74), Geneva (Genève), Plan-les-Ouates, Thônex, Troinex"
[14] "www.veyrier.ch SFSO statistics"
```

I am able to populate the table with only elevation data and not area and density. Please help. Thanks!

```
# Clean text and store in data frame
  canton_table[canton_table$name == current_name, "area"] <- helper_function(" • Total", labels, data)
  canton_table[canton_table$name == current_name, "elevation"] <- helper_function("Elevation", labels, data)
  canton_table[canton_table$name == current_name, "density"] <- helper_function(" • Density", labels, data)
```

My output table:
[My output table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c7P0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the labels name in the labels array, from " • Total" to "Total" eccs.
The names like this " • Total" are probably giving references problems.
And then create the table

```
  canton_table[canton_table$name == current_name, "area"] <- helper_function("Total", labels, data)
```

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. My table still has N/A values.